# «Заднее число» — метафора?

Tags: фразеология, метафора

Является ли сочетание "задним числом" метафорой? Ведь число действительно на абстрактно выстроенной временной ленте может находиться в определённом месте по отношению к настоящему моменту.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [**Задним числом**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://kartaslov.ru/%25D0%25B7%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B0%25D1%2587%25D0%25B5%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B5-%25D1%2581%25D0%25BB%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B0/%25D0%25B7%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B4%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BC%2520%25D1%2587%25D0%25B8%25D1%2581%25D0%25BB%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BC&ved=2ahUKEwjrtrbUkvzpAhVxBhAIHRo1DtgQFjABegQICxAF&usg=AOvVaw0k_-XhwHPLSd447BcPuskT) — 1) более ранним, чем было на самом деле, прошедшим числом (о дате на письме, документе). *Пометить записку **задним числом***; 2) позднее, спустя некоторое время. ***Задним числом** Трегубов сообразил, что крыса появилась в классе неспроста.*

[**Задним числом**](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC)

> Устойчивое сочетание (**фразеологизм**). Используется в качестве наречной группы.

[**Чем метафора отличается от фразеологизма?**](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/leksika/metafora-otlichaetsia-frazeologizma.html)

> **Фразеологизм** — это лексически спаянное выражение, в котором невозможна замена слов. Например, во фразеологизме *«биться как рыба об лед»*, если поменять некоторые его компоненты  (*валяться как рыба об лед, молчать как рыба об лед, биться как щука об лед*), то фразеологизм исчезнет, потеряется его переносный смысл «бедствовать», «бороться с нуждой».
>
> В **метафоре** нет такого монолитного единства слов. Например, слово «огонь» метафорически можно употребить с другими существительными и возникает иной художественный образ: *огонь души; огонь сердца; огонь взгляда.*
>
> **Фразеологизм** является **готовой лексической единицей**, которую мы воспроизводим в своей речи в любой момент, когда этого требует речевая ситуация. А **метафору создает единожды художник слова** в определенном контексте, в закрепленной речевой ситуации.

Comment: Но ведь существуют же "устойчивые метафоры"?

Comment: @ВладимирЖеребцов  Наверное, да, если покопаться. Но метафора – это больше сравнение, которое вариативно. А в данном случае, если заменить "заднее" на, скажем, "предыдущее", уйдёт ёмкость, устойчивость, образность сочетания.

Comment: Устойчивая метафора и есть фразеологизм